# why PUT method hit form action route?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mern, react-fullstack

First thing first try to understand the situation!!

I have deployed the app on Heroku..
this is a **MERN Stack** app, doing crud operations
all the operations are working fine but the update is not working (I'm using put method)

Here is my form code

```
 <Form
    action="/newentry"
    method="POST"
    encType="multipart/form-data"
   onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  >
```

Update button code:

```
 <button
  className="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg m-3"
   onClick={()=> handleEdit}
   >
     Update
     </button>
```

handleEdit Code:

```
const handleEdit = async (e) => {
const studata = {
 
  fname: info.fname,
  lname: info.lname,
  fathername: info.fathername,
  occupation: info.occupation,
  dob: info.dob,
};

await axios.put("/api/update", studata);
await swal({
  title: "Profile updated!",
  icon: "success",
  button: "Ok",
})
  .then(() => {
    navigate(-1);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })};
```

**THE PROBLEM**

whenever I hit Update button it redirects to the form action page which is "/newentry"

500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: How will my data go to the backend if I remove my "action=/newentry"?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `action="/newentry"` from the `form. What` action`do is redirect the user to the provided URL. When you send data through`axios` you don't want to redirect the user.